# Add User To Role in Membership Provider

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have gone through a video tutorial regarding `Asp.net Membership Provider` in which he has done his coding in `VB`. The same code i used in `C#` but at this point i am getting an error as `The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Security.Roles.AddUsersToRole(string[], string)' has some invalid arguments`

This is what i have written with reference to that video can any one tell what's going wrong

`Roles.AddUsersToRole(User.Identity.Name, ListBox1.SelectedValue);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shoud use :

[Roles.AddUserToRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.addusertorole.aspx)

instead of :

[Roles.AddUsersToRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.adduserstorole.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
Roles.AddUsersToRole(new string[] {User.Identity.Name}, ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

this should to the trick

Answer (score 0):

I think, in fact, that this is needed:

```
Roles.AddUsersToRole(new string[] {User.Identity.Name}, ListBox1.SelectedValue);
```

based on the method signature shown.